# Pouring a concrete slab porch onto corrugated metal with no cross support

Tags: concrete

[image]We are building a front porch that is approximately 8 feet off the ground. Our builder laid a piece of corrugated steel down that he supported on the front with the center block wall and brick and a supported on the rear by a 2x10 board mounted to the floor joices by screws or nails.  There are no other reinforcements at all. We asked if the builder was going to put steel cross members to support the weight of the concrete is the going to be okay?

Comment: More information is needed. Size of the concrete slab over the metal and support walls. Thickness of the concrete pour and type of re-bar being used and how it is installed. Be aware that with proper type construction it is possible to create a clear span concreted pour that can support itself as long as it has proper support and foundation under all of its edges. Years ago we built a two car garage floor over a basement boat house that was clear span. The main floor itself was just 5 inches thick but was poured over a matrix of inverted box forms (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) that were themselves about 15 inches in height. The space between these boxes created what was in principle concrete beams integral to the floor above that had carefully engineered rebar in them. Of course this whole area had a temporary platform built under it with several layers of plywood and lots of posts down to the floor in the bottom of the boat house. I mean lots of posts! - that were to support the weight of the concrete till it cured. Afterwards the posts, plywood platform and the wood box forms were all removed. Most of the material was used elsewhere.

Comment: How wide is the porch? (Which is also how long (in the corrugation direction) is the span for the corrugated sheet?) Corrugated steel is used to support concrete slab floor pours in skyscrapers. Depending on a bunch of details we don't know, it may have all the support it needs - the depth of the corrugations, the thickness of the steel, the span, the thickness of the slab pour... Did you go look at other concrete slab porches your builder has successfully built, or are you going to be their first?

Comment: These are things I will have to check on.  Thanks for the thoughts!